# Who Killed the Biology Teacher?

Tags: riddle

It is the first day of school and the biology teacher has been killed.

The detective is called and interrogates four suspects.

He asks the first one, the P.E teacher. The P.E teacher tells the detective that he was playing basketball with one of his students.

The headmaster says that he was working in his office.

The math teacher said that he was holding a mid-year test.

The Gardner says he was gardening.

Who is the Killer???

Only use the hint if very stuck!!!

> Look at the days and time!!!

Here is were this riddle came from - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0zrRIN_T5E
Thank you to Bright Side!!!

Comment: This is too easy, but good start!

Comment: Is there any reason you rolled back QuantumTwinkie's formatting edit?

Comment: @DragonMaster When a puzzle is not your own creation -- as this one clearly isn't, being readily found elsewhere on the internet -- you need to say where you got it from (and, when it's somewhere on the internet, provide a link). Could you edit appropriately, please? Thanks.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan it’s probably the third riddle of this link: https://brightside.me/wonder-quizzes/7-mystery-crime-riddles-only-a-true-detective-can-solve-374160/

Comment: That was my guess too.

Comment: You can only provide the check mark once. I'm not that attached to it, but you gave it for my answer first, so what changed your mind to give it to QuantumTwinkie?

Comment: Check Mark???What do you mean???

Comment: give it to QuantumTwinkie???

Comment: @DragonMaster Sorry I will reformulate. On your questions you can accept only one answer (which gives a green mark above the vote points). If you accept another answer, that removes the mark from the previous accepted answer to give it to the newly accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> The Math teacher as he was holding a mid-year exam on the first day of school

Answer (score 8):

The murderer is

> The math teacher

Because

> It is the first day of school, and he claimed holding a mid-year test

Comment: You beat me by seconds :D

Comment: 6 seconds i believe

Comment: 23 actually ;) You can hover the "answered ... ago" to see the timestamp

Comment: I have a problem!!!

Comment: Do you know how to make sure that the hint is only available when hovering over the hint???

Comment: @DragonMaster You rollbacked QuantumTwinkie's edit. He solved this problem. You seem eager to contribute to this site but don't rush things, learn by reading other puzzles and raw texts to understand the syntax

Comment: @DragonMaster To make breaks between paragraphs, add two spaces at the end of a line **or** type "<br>" where you want the "break." To make a hint (or details of an answer) hidden add ">!" to the beginning. [Check this page out!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help)